# two-factor authentication not working, not even asking me for security code

Tags: iphone, icloud, password, keychain, two-factor-authentication

I'm in a bit of a difficult situation at the moment. I have an iPhone 6 and a MacBook Air, which are both asking me for two-factor authentication every day. The only problem is, all that ever seems to happen is a never-ending "waiting for device". In order to do that it asks for my phone password on my phone and my computer and Apple ID password on my computer. I've read some answers here and they all say to turn off Keychain and then turn it on again to enter the security code, but when I tried that there was no little box for the security code. I really need an answer since I may get a new phone and I won't be able to upload my iCloud drive if I don't get this fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually obtain a verification code

- iPhone: Settings → Apple ID → Password & Security → Get Verification Code.
- Mac: System Preferences → iCloud → Account Details → Security → Get A Verification Code.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is it won't actually let me enter the code anywhere.